# How to effectively pass arguments through many functions

Tags: c++, c++11

From some time we can hear a lot that value semanthics is really important in C++ (i.e. [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eR34r7HOU14) and [here](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value)). I know that we should use it especially when we intend to copy the value inside the body of the function anyway. So I assume that such a usage is fair:

```
void foo(std::string txt) { my_container.emplace_back(move(txt)); }
```

However I did not find any recommendation what to do if I have to pass that argument through a big tree of functions which sometimes happens in a big project. So for example:

```
void bar(std::string txt) { foo(move(txt)); /* more actions */ }
void boo(std::string txt) { bar(move(txt)); /* more actions */ }
```

Can someone recommend what to do in such a case? Should we stay with value semantics and hope that compiler optimizer will be able to limit number of move operations or use const references everywhere and only one copy at the end? Or maybe, as in many cases in C++, it depends (i.e. cost of copy and move for specific type)? :-)

Comment: const references are always a safe bet :)

Comment: I know they say you should stick with values and moves, but I still use `const` refs personally. Sue me. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do the same :-) However every time I do it I feel bad and wonder if that is the best thing to do. That is why I asked...

Comment: This problem (*What type of pass by value is most efficient?*) is generated from the sense of pass by value/reference inherited from C. In C pass by value equals to pass by copy, and pass by reference equals to pass a reference (A pointer) by value. That is, when in C we say *"pass by value"* we means ***"pass copying"***, and when we say *pass by reference"* we means ***"pass a reference"***. ...

Comment: ... this problem is extended in C++ with the concept of references. A reference is nothing much than a pointer-makeup. A reference is a pointer whith only the operations of pointers related to its meaning of "references". That is, without pointer-arithmetic, null, etc. This feature (references) allows C++ programmers to use pure references (i.e. pass a reference without the unsafety-prone features of pointers). But on the other hand, adds a new type of passing: Pass a read-only reference. This could be viewed as a efficient pass by value, ...

Comment: ... but people are puzzled because when we think, as I noted before, pass by value we think about copying. Pass by value is pass by value, that is, passing a variable to a function, unmodifiable by the body of the function. **How this "unmodifiable" contract is implemented** (Copying the variable or passing a read-only reference) is not the point. **This is the problem (A conceptual problem) that most of C and C++ programmers have** (I`m included :) ).

Comment: This conceptual misunderstanding is not related to C/C++ only, is a common conceptual problem in Java, where the the standard says that ***Java has pass-by-value only***, but you can modify the instance passed to the function (Because Java really uses the concept of reference pass of C, that is, **Passing a reference (Pointer) by value**).

Answer (score 1):

In general it depends on cost of copy and move for specific type(and even objects) and how it's called(with temporaries or not, etc)

For example for temporary `boo(gimme_t())`:

Let `d` is depth of tree of yours classes

Solution with `move`s cost `d * COST_OF_MOVE`, solution with `COST_OF_COPY + d * REF_ASSIGNMENT`.

You can see that for `std::string` it's `O(d)` vs `O(n)` so for strings with big lengths it's cheaper to use moves (and for short strings it's not so important), but for `std::array<int>` it's `O(nd)` vs `O(n + d)`, so you'd better use one copy.

But if argument isn't temporary (`T t; boo(t)`) costs will be:

`COST_OF_COPY + d * COST_OF_MOVE` vs `COST_OF_COPY + d * REF_ASSIGNMENT`, so const-ref solution is faster by `d` moves.

But if you may consider `move` almost free™ you'd better use move solution to avoid 1 copy in case of temporary argument

---

(*) Everywhere you should read `d ± 1` instead of `d`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I think so too, but wanted to make sure. And of course I am asking for "movable" types (those for which move is cheaper than copy).However still I would like to hear how it affects optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

For templates and template-like solutions you should obviously go with perfect forwarding. In other cases, forcing a copy via `foo(MyType copy)` declaration seems needles. Avoid costs, and copy when you must, even if via copy-elision the compiler might be little more efficient than move operations.